# Is there a way to get the deleted security groups from Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph API to sync users and groups to my application. recently I've been trying to use the deleted items endpoint to get deleted security groups so I can update them on my end, but the endpoint always seems to return an empty response. this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62259215/shouldnt-members-be-part-of-list-of-deleted-groups-in-microsoft-graph-ad) seems to indicate that security groups won't actually be returned to this endpoint. is there some way to list deleted security groups in Microsoft Graph API?

Comment: Unfortunately it's by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's by design. As Allen suggested above, consider upvote the user voice, so that it can be implemented

Answer (score 1):

You have find the correct answer from that thread.

Azure AD security groups are not going to the recycle bin and cannot be restored, so we **CAN'T** get deleted security groups currently.

You can vote up the related [User Voice post](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/35083381-restore-azure-active-directory-security-groups).

Answer (score 0):

When you delete a Security group in Azure Active Directory (Azure AD),the deleted group is not retained. It cannot be recovered. This was really unexpected. To restore deleted security groups, you need to manually recreate them and add the users again. But who has backups or information to recreate the groups and add the users again? Since Azure AD does not have backup for it, administrators should take the backup for security groups to quickly restore those groups if needed. Below is the sample script to take the backup of all groups and save those information in csv file.

please refer more details in the blog below:
[Restore Azure AD Group](https://blog.dsynctech.com/how-to-restore-an-azure-ad-group-that-has-been-deleted-by-mistake-praveen-kumar)